# jquery mobile and multiline header?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to add a line of text in the header (but not make the default header height bigger).  Is this possible?

```
<div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
    <h1><?=$song_title;?><br/><?=$artist_name;?></h1>
</div>
```

All I get is a larger header height with multilines because the font doesn't change it's size.

How can I edit this so the font is smaller and thus can squeeze another line up there?  but not affect the rest of the css for other pages?

Comment: You can use custom styling and target that specific header, for example `<h1 class="multiLineHeader"> long text here </h1>` and then `.multiLineHeader { font-size: 9px; }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran into this issue too. You have to override the css like this.

http://jsfiddle.net/7EP7U/1/

```
#page2 .ui-header h1 {
  font-size: .7em;   
}​
```